# What do you call the artwork you first see upon entering a place

Tags: single-word-requests

- When you open the front doors of a building and enter, you would be greeted by this statue or painting.
- After you enter a campus by car, you would encounter this sculpture or fountain.
- An building's vestibule, or foyer would often have this prominent statue or painting.
- A cemetery would have a statue right behind its front gates.
- In the Museum of Natural History, Washington, D.C., it would be the elephant.

What would you call this artwork or decoration placement?

Comment: The Fénykövi Elephant is the _______ of the Museum of Natural History.

Answer (score 7):

According to my wife, who is trained in Art History, this is a *marquee piece* from the word *marquee* meaning a sign placed at the entrance of a building.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the term ***"centerpiece"***

> (n.) an item or issue intended to be a focus of attention: *the tower is the centerpiece of the park.*

Definition from *New Oxford American Dictionary*

> *The Fénykövi Elephant is the centerpiece of the Museum of Natural History.*

Comment: That's relative to the room though, not the entire building or campus. E.g., you wouldn't actually say "The Fénykövi Elephant is the centerpiece of the Museum of Natural History," because it's not.

Comment: Agreed @SevenSidedDie; centerpiece is a very poor suggestion for the nuances of the word being requested.

Comment: Isn't centerpiece in the center?  Or maybe it is the most important in some cases.  Either way really not the question.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd figuratively speaking, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If this piece of art puts you in the right mood for the rest of the exhibits, if it has the same functions as a starter course in a meal you could say:

> The Fénykövi Elephant is the tone setter art piece of the Museum of Natural History.
>
> Tone setter *[a person or thing that establishes the quality or
>   character that is to be followed subsequently](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tone-setter)*

or,  more figuratively, borrowing from music and drama:

> The Fénykövi Elephant is the opening act of the Museum of Natural History.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this artworks  usually  located in important parts of buildings so that they can be very visible and attract the attention of guests or visitors can be called: **high spots** or **focal points**.

Comment: The artwork is called high spots?  What if the painting is of squares?

Comment: OP is quite generic regarding the definition of an artwork ( statue, fountain, elephant, or paintings) so depending on the context, high spot or focal point may fit, I think.

Comment: Can you use high spots in a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

How about the word ***frontispiece***?

Comment: I looked it up, and it exists. Why don't posters give an explanation or at least provide a link?

Answer (score -1):

Centerpieces have specific names:

> **[Nef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nef_%28metalwork%29)** is an extravagant table ornament and container used in the Middle Ages and Renaissance, made of precious metals in the shape of a
>   ship
>
> **[Pergne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epergne)** is a type of table centerpiece, usually made
>   of silver, but may be made of any metal or glass or porcelain.

A [**collectors piece**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collectors+piece) is generally prominently exhibited

Comment: A collectors piece is probably displayed in a collector's home.  The other two answers... I have no idea how you came up with them.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd next time you are in a museum, I Double Dog Dare Ya to ask a docent

Comment: I am at art museums all the time.  I will ask them where they are keeping the nef and pergne.  They will have the same expression as I did when reading the answer.