# What to call statues that flank entryways?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, history

What's the term for statuary, usually paired, which flank entrances?

Ex: The Lion pedestals at the NYC Public library; Assyrian Ox-God statues built into gates of ancient cities.

My placeholder term is "sentinel statues," but I suspect there's an official one.

Comment: This question strongly reminded me of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173159/what-do-you-call-the-artwork-you-first-see-upon-entering-a-place/173225#173225 but on closer examination they are a bit different.

Comment: [***Caryatids***](http://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/highlight_objects/gr/c/caryatid_from_the_erechtheion.aspx)?

Comment: I think the marquee statue would be the first statue they intend for you to see in the museum. So in a natural history museum example, the marquee statue might be the big statue of a dinosaur in the rotunda. It's not the main exhibit, but it "sets the mood". The stairway statues are the first ones you actually see, but I don't think they're the marquee statues. They have more of a guardian purpose.

Comment: @DanBron the statue built into the gate wouldn't be a Caryatid because it isn't a isolate post-support. I hadn't considered their function as part of the building, though, only as decorations, so thank you.

Answer (score 16):

They are generally referred to as ***guardian statues***. One of the most popular types is *guardian lions*.

For example, Chinese guardian lions ("Foo Dogs") are well-known and it is mentioned that they share symbolism with Staffordshire dogs:

> While Staffordshire dogs originated in 19th-century England, like foo dogs they were used as symbols of protection and status. Staffordshire dogs were often found flanking the fireplace in well-to-do British homes, and were strikingly similar in pose and scale — I can’t help but wonder if they were at all influenced by these ancient **guardian statues** of China.
>
> [taliejaneinteriors.com](http://taliejaneinteriors.com/7-things-to-know-about-foo-dogs/)

The lion statues of the NYC Library are mentioned as *guardian lions*  in the book *Public Space* by Stephen Carr:

> The monumental neoclassic white marble building of the New York Public Library in mid-Manhattan, its forecourt flanked by two reclining **"guardian lions"** sculpted by Edward C. ...

[image]
<sub>newyork.com</sub>

They are referred to as **gate guardians** as well:

> Statue of a pair of lions often founds in temples in Southeast Asia as the **gate guardian.**  The Balinese winged lion often served as the **guardian statue** or as the pedestal of wooden column.
>
> <sub>[*Wikipedia / Cultural depictions of lions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_depictions_of_lions)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Dvarapala (Sanskrit) is a **door or gate guardian** often portrayed as warrior or fearsome asura giant, usually armed with a weapon, the most common is gadha mace.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[*Wikipedia / Dvarapala*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvarapala)</sub>

*Gate-guardian sculpture* is mentioned in the book "What is stronger than a lion?: leonine image and metaphor in the Hebrew Bible and the ancient Near East" by  Brent A. Strawn:

[image]

Comment: @CaseyM: You're welcome. I also learnt more about them when searching.

Comment: The heraldic term is _Supporters_, like the hippos on the [arms of Ankh-Morpork](http://41.media.tumblr.com/96fb4e9bfedb8b3131f8e7b58f7d8a04/tumblr_nfin87es8P1qzcl9lo1_500.jpg)